# Looking to somehow get control of my LG Optimus G with broken screen..

Tags: usb-debugging, touchscreen, lg, broken-screen

I dropped my phone the other day, and the screen cracked rendering it completely useless as it made the digitizer break. I have no touch control of my phone whatsoever, I reset it like an idiot to see if maybe the digitizer will decide to work again (so its no longer connected to wifi at the moment). I'm wondering if there is any way whatsoever to control this phone from my PC, without USB debugging enabled (or, if there is a way to enable USB debugging from an unrooted device). I do not plan on replacing the screen, as the phone is a little outdated now. Any suggestion is appreciated highly, I just simply wanna be able to get some sort of use out of this phone before letting it go for $20 on kijiji.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already checked with our [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info)? Plenty of useful hints there.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take it to a place where they fix phones. They can fix the screen for you. Depending on who you go with, the prices will vary. Other than that, I doubt there will be any other way.